# Android Key Listener

Tags: android, keylistener

Hello i have one key listener

```
 email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);

email.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if(keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

        }
    });
```

but when I press enter the event does not work, any idea?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: you just return true..try adding a toast message saying enter pressed or something to test it

Comment: the event dont execute never...

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for the [OnKeyListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html).

> Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a hardware key
>   event is dispatched to this view. The callback will be invoked before
>   the key event is given to the view. This is only useful for hardware
>   keyboards; a software input method has no obligation to trigger this
>   listener.

I'm guessing your are not using a hardware keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i have one solution, im add a android:singleLine="true", regards!

```
 <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:background="@drawable/customs_borders"
            android:textColor="#ffd3e8d6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="23dp"
            android:hint="EMAIL"
            android:singleLine="true"/>
```